# Locate me data obtained from european register

Tags: gdpr

There is an entry on locatefamily.com that I know because it has certain details that were used on a European domain register in 2014. I an EU citizen living in the states. Does the GDPR apply to them in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Well Cindy,

To begin with the website does process Personal Data from hundreds or hundreds of thousands of natural persons, many of whom are likely to reside in the EU and it does not comply with GDPR... How can I say this?! Well, the Privacy Policy states that:

"... If you feel that information displayed on LocateFamily.com is private in nature and you would like said information removed from view, please complete and submit the form on our removal page..."

that means they process Data anyhow and then if people request to opt-out they will then consider erasure; GDPR requires a Lawful Base for processing Personal Data and they do it without having a documented one.

If you used to live in the EU and you now live in the U.S., GDPR only applies to them if they are an EU established company, if they are not established in the EU and you are not an EU resident, then GDPR does not apply.

Note that it is not a matter of "citizenship" yet one of "residency", unless you reside in the EU and you are temporarily in the U.S.

The other thing that is "troubling me" is when you mention:

"... certain details that were used on a European domain register in 2014..."

this points in a direction (for now just speculation) that this company may have (somehow) incorporated 3rd party DataBase content (containing Personal Data) without (potentially) thousands of people, not having been informed.

What can you do (under GDPR that is):

1st -  If the company is established in the EU, submit a Data Subject Access Request; if not get someone you know who resides in the EU to do it (as themselves).
2nd if the answer does not arrive within 1 month or it is not according to GDPR requirements, present a complaint towards the Supervisory Authority (of the European country the person resides in) and further submit a formal complaint towards the Company.

These matters will only start to move once people start presenting formal complaints.